# Alternative download options for `pip` sources.

Tags: python, download, installation, pip, download-manager

I would like to install a set of packages from `requirements.txt`. `pip` seems to be incredibly slow in the default operation (1~5 kbps).

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The following command was not much of help either; the download was still slow.

```
pip install --download DIR -r requirements.txt
```

The objective now is to download those package from the same link that `pip` would prefer, but download them with an accelerator (like `axel` achieving 500-700 kbps) to a directory `DIR`. Then I would be able to install them locally using the command.

```
 pip install --no-index --find-links=DIR -r requirements.txt
```

How could I do this?

Specs: Pip-6.0.6, Python-2.7, Mac OS X 10.9

PS: All this to install Odoo (formerly OpenERP).

Comment: Are u saying download speed is low, but I downloaded and installed python packages from pip at around 850kbps

Comment: @Bhanukiran: Yes, exactly, pip always seem to work at low bandwidth for me with the upper limit of 30 kbps while the actual connection goes up to 500 kbps. I just don't know why. Besides, I'm not the only one who feels pip is slow.

Comment: I assume u r on ubuntu(linux),so use this command, sudo apt-get install pychart where pychart is python package name replace it with your required package.

Comment: @Bhanukiran: sorry but I doubt you've read the last line of my post -- it's OS-X